# java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist "FirebaseStorage"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

Whenever i trying to test the sample in this link i got this error
[https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start]

```
FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
```

my gradle file is

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

}
}
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'android'


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.6.1'
          compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.1'

// Google Play Services

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
// Firebase Client
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.6.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
//Storage and authin
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.1'
//multidex
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


}

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "24"

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.pay.my_admin"
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 24
multiDexEnabled true
 }
  afterEvaluate {
  tasks.matching {
  it.name.startsWith('dex')
  }.each { dx ->
  if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
     dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
  } else {
     dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
  }
  }
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                                             'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

   }

 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }


 sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debu   /AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I already checked others question and tried the solution that they suggested but the issue still.

Please note that i am using eclipse.

Comment: Have you included `google-services.json` in your app as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup ?

Comment: Yes, I already add it, please note that i using eclipse

Comment: Try `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`.  That's the current version.

Comment: What Gradle tasks do you use to build and run?

Comment: Still same error, actually i got the error in this line "FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();"

i am trying to upload photo to firebase storage.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. I think you should sign in before getting an object of FirebaseStorage.

Put this code in onCreate() of your launcher activity

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Then in onStart(), check the FirebaseUser value. If user is null, sign in anonymously.

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
  // do your stuff
} else {
  signInAnonymously();
}
```

signInAnonymously()

```
private void signInAnonymously() {
    mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnSuccessListener(this, new  OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                // do your stuff
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "signInAnonymously:FAILURE", exception);
            }
        });
}
```